# No matter what the query is, sometimes it delayed so much

Tags: java, mysql, centos

I programmed at centos(6.2final), mysql 5.1.66 and java jdk 1.6.

this code get me server's result.

```
public ArrayList confirm(String key, String string) {
        ArrayList tmp = null;

        try {
            PreparedStatement prep = null;
            try {
                prep = Local.prepareStatement("select distinct tags from tagDB where key=? and string!=?;");
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            if (prep != null) {
                prep.setString(1, key);
                prep.setString(2, string);

                int count = getRowCount(prep.executeQuery());
                if (count > 0) {
                    tmp = new ArrayList();
                    ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        tmp.add(rs.getString("tags"));
                    }
                    return tmp;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

and db of server is good. I think so.

if you want to see mysql. I can get it to you.

my log from java is below.

```
16:2:46:450, turnaround time :26

16:2:46:484, turnaround time :23

...

16:2:47:665, turnaround time :23

16:2:50:136, turnaround time :71

16:2:50:246, turnaround time :106

...

16:2:53:22, turnaround time :54

**16:2:58:131, turnaround time :5098**

16:2:58:157, turnaround time :22

...

16:2:58:325, turnaround time :23

**16:3:3:358, turnaround time :5028**

**16:3:8:423, turnaround time :5027**

16:3:9:525, turnaround time :22

...

16:3:10:248, turnaround time :64

**16:3:15:288, turnaround time :5032**
```

Sometimes it delayed 5000ms exactly.

So I think it happens because of server's memory or buffer setting, like GC of java.

So I edit my.cnf(config file of mysql).
about size of maxconnection, max_heap_table_size,
max_tmp_table_size, thread_cache_size and so on.
(i failed to adjust value of thread_cache_size and some table thing.
my.cnf file doesn't adjust above two value....)

than nothing happened.

mysql's slow query log can't get anything.

... anything i can't do more. so please.. and appreciate so much to read all....

so much. have a good day you all.

ps. my english is not good.. i know. sorry about that too.^^;

Comment: Why do you run prep.executeQuery() twice ? Why use the count control anyway when you loop thru ResultSet ?

Comment: The delay could be the GC. How many rows has the ResultSet typically ?

Comment: @PeterMmm om,, i think that's not gc of java... cause my db is so small have some thousands of rows and resultset can get maximum 2 rows normally.

Comment: ToDo: profile Java prog, run query from a shell, check for network problems, ...